# How to run a Job from SQL Server Agent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

It is possible to execute a **Job** from **SQL Server Agent** in **ASP.Net** page triggered by clicking a **button**?

Comment: Cant you just execute a stored procedure with a button click that executes the job you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sp_start_job (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Instructs SQL Server Agent to execute a job immediately.

---

> [ @job_name= ] 'job_name'
>
> The name of the job to start. Either job_id or job_name must be
>   specified, but both cannot be specified. job_name is sysname, with a
>   default of NULL.

You can use it as a store procedure than run it in your code.

If your job runs a dts package, you can use [`Package.Execute method`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190901.aspx)

> Returns a DTSExecResult enumeration that contains information about
>   the success or failure of the package execution.

Example from *MSDN* page;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Package p = new Package();
        p.InteractiveMode = true;
        p.OfflineMode = true;

        // Add a Script Task to the package.
        TaskHost taskH = (TaskHost)p.Executables.Add(typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask).AssemblyQualifiedName);
        // Run the package.
        p.Execute();
        // Review the results of the run.
        if (taskH.ExecutionResult == DTSExecResult.Failure || taskH.ExecutionStatus == DTSExecStatus.Abend)
            Console.WriteLine("Task failed or abended");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Task ran successfully");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, using sp_start_job does the trick but is there also a way to check if the job were successfully executed like you coded for DTS package?

Comment: @FairHaven Yes. `sp_start_job` returns 0 (success) or 1 (failure). Check the documentation. If you find these answers usefull, don't forget to upvote and accept one of these..

Answer (score 1):

Use [sp_start_job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) stored procedure.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'YourJobName';
```

Comment: Hi, what is the purpose of the N letter besides the JobName?

Comment: It's about NVARCHAR datatype which signifies an UNICODE string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible . You may also use

```
Server server = new Server("<replace_with_your_server>");
server.JobServer.Jobs["<replace_with_your_job_name>"]?.Start();
```

More details at [Start, Stop, Manage MS SQL Server Agent Job using C#](https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/start-stop-manage-ms-sql-server-agent-jobs-using-c-sharp/)